# How can I get jQuery .val() AFTER keypress event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, jquery-events

I got:

```
$(someTextInputField).keypress(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Now the alert always returns the value BEFORE the `keypress` (e.g. the field is empty, I type 'a' and the alert gives me ''. Then I type 'b' and the alert gives me 'a'...). But I want the value AFTER the `keypress` - how can I do that?

Background: I'd like to enable a button as soon as the text field contains at least one character. So I run this test on every `keypress` event, but using the returned `val()` the result is always one step behind. Using the `change()` event is not an option for me because then the button is disabled until you leave the text box. If there's a better way to do that, I'm glad to hear it!

Comment: Should the button become disabled again if the text is deleted?  If so, you'll probably have to stick with keypress.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Change `keypress` to `keyup`:

```
$(someTextInputField).on("keyup", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

`keypress` is fired when the key is pressed down, `keyup` is fired when the key is released.

Comment: @Brilliand You're right. I made a workaround for this, it's posted below.

Comment: how who you accomplisch this on iPhone/Android devices? They don't support the keyup function.

Comment: definition of keypress is not exactly correct. that's the definition of keydown. see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Answer (score 64):

Surprised that no one mentioned the js "input" event:

```
$(someTextInputField).on('input', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Recommended.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: Wow, this is the answer to several unanswered/badly answered SO questions.

Comment: This is also great when you need to ignore pressing arrow keys, shift etc. in input field.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=input Relatively good browser support. Much better answer than listening to every keyup.

Comment: It saves my day! Thank you. 
I used the following code:
$('.subject_mark').on("input", function () {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, function (str) {
            return '';
        }));

Answer (score 9):

instead of keypress, use **[keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)**.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
$('#someField').keypress(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($('#someField').val().length > 0)
      $('#theButton').attr('disabled', false);
  }, 1);
});
```

That simply introduces a timeout so that after the "keypress" event loop completes, your code will run almost immediately thereafter. Such a short timer interval (even if rounded up by the browser) will not be noticeable.

*edit* — or you *could* use "keyup" like everybody else says, though its semantics are different.

Comment: It's not a matter of benig *smart*.  The keyup event doesn't provide the same result. You get distinct events for shift, ctrl,etc with keyup - if you want to get the actual character being typed (such as an ampersand) rather than a series of key events that you have to check the state of shift or ctrl keys, keypress is the way to go.

Comment: Right; that's what I meant by "it's semantics are different".

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use the keydown event with a timeout of 0.

That way, the changes will be applied instantly, instead of being applied when the user stops holding the key.

```
$(someTextInputField).on("keydown", function() {
  setTimeout(function($elem){
    alert($elem.val());
  }, 0, $(this));
});
```

Comment: This will still behave strangely in the case of holding down Backspace... perhaps keypress with a timeout of 0?

Comment: Ah, never mind, the OP doesn't specify what should happen if the text field is cleared.