# How to capture the onscreen keyboard 'keydown' and 'keyup' events for touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, touch, on-screen-keyboard

I have defined keyboard events which is working good in desktop but for touch devices not getting the onscreen keyboard event. I need to capture if user is typing. I have used the following segment of code :

```
$('#id').keydown(function(e){
  //some code here
});

$('#id').keyup(function(e){
  //some code here
})
```

I want the code defined in `keydown` and `keyup` to trigger even for touch devices (both tablets and mobiles). Please suggest how to capture the onscreen keyboard event and make the above code to run.

Comment: About which devices in particular are you talking about? The above code works on Safari for iPhone/Pad/Pod.

Comment: @mamoo ipad,iphone,android. But this is not working for me in safari

Comment: I tested the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/dzKtw/1/ and it works for me...

Comment: does it work with setInterval function. I have defined setInterval and in every 1 sec i am checking if text box is blank or user has typed any text and alternatively hiding or displaying the clear text image. But this does not seem to work in my case not undersanding why

Comment: How to tackle this problem in Android devices?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25172585/312598

Comment: Android bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

Comment: This one is relevant: even if you get the event, you still need to jump through hoops to get the keycode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried using key press instead of key down

```
$("#id").keypress(function() {

});
```

Updated :

Due to android problems I now normally wrap my checks like this

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $("#id").keypress (keyPress);
} else {
    $("#id").keydown (keyPress);
}

function keyPress(e){
    doSomething;
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty old answer now, I think recently I have come across this problem and have solved it for now by doing a simple check. I have updated my answer see if that works, let me know how you get on.

Comment: `$.browser` deprecated and removed in jq 1.9.

Comment: I am using vue3, and it seems keyup fires, but keypress does not (Android 9, Chrome 88.0.4324.181).
If your situation is like mine and you're using the events to do some form of validation or evaluation, the solution could be to rethink the requirements and combine the functions.

Answer (score 1):

> One way to solve this is by using `setInterval` when `keyup` or
>   `keydown` events are not detected.

```
var keyUpFired = false;
$('#input').on('keyup',function() {
    keyUpFired = true;
    // do something
});
if( keyUpFired === false) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if($('#input').val().length>0) {
        // do something         
        }
    },100); 
}
```

Here is a small example using `Materialize` in order to test in touch devices.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var keyUpFired = false;
$('#input').on('keyup',function() {
keyUpFired = true;
if ($('#input').get(0).checkValidity() === true) {
$('label[for="input"]').attr('data-success','Custom Success Message: You typed...'+$(this).val());
} else {
$('label[for="input"]').attr('data-error','Custom Error Message: Username too small');          
}
validate_field($('#input')); 
});
if( keyUpFired == false) {
setInterval(function() {
if($('#input').val().length>0) {
if ($('#input').get(0).checkValidity() !== false) {
$('label[for="input"]').attr('data-success','Custom Success Message: You typed...'+$('#input').val());
} else {
$('label[for="input"]').attr('data-error','Custom Error Message: Username too small');          
}
validate_field($('#input'));  
}
},100); 
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input placeholder="5-20 characters..." id="input" pattern=".{5,20}" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="input" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Username</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The last answer on this page works: 
[How can I get jquery .val() AFTER keypress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063434/how-can-i-get-jquery-val-after-keypress-event) -

Basically discard the "keyup" and change to "input", something like:
$(document).delegate('#q', 'input', function(e) { etc }