# Keyboard "Swipe" Javascript Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a **web app** that includes a search box that updates results as the user types.

The mechanism works because it is implemented identically on the desktop version.

The problem that I am having with it is that none of the event listeners (`keydown, keyup, paste`) are fired when the user enters text using a swipe input method.

Listening for a `change event` also doesn't work since the `input` must lose focus for the event to be fired.

With keyboards like `Swype` and `Android's` new keyboard supporting swiping this will be an easily noticed deficiency. What event should I listen for to detect this input?

Comment: Looks like you want the `input` event instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture the onscreen keyboard 'keydown' and 'keyup' events for touch devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940829/how-to-capture-the-onscreen-keyboard-keydown-and-keyup-events-for-touch-devi)

Comment: @SpaceDog Thank you! I wish comments could be marked as answers on here.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, just to make it easy to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `input` event fires on each change to an input field (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/FJe3t/1/)) -- so you should use that instead of the other events. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input