# iOS 9 - keyup event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios9, keyup, onkeyup

Is anybody else having problems with the `keyup` event in iOS 9 not firing?

Just a simple test bed replicates the issue for me.

```
<input id="txtInput" />
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```
document.getElementById('txtInput').onkeyup = function () {
    console.log('keyup triggered');
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#txtInput').on('keyup', function () {
    console.log('keyup triggered');
});
```

Neither fire...

Comment: Onscreen or external keyboard?  Are you sure it's just iOS 9?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9940829/594235

Comment: On-screen. And yeah 100% - the event fired in iOS 8 and before, and Android. Thanks - looking now.

Comment: experienced the same issue. any fix so far?

Comment: Hmm, it's not great - but I have answered this below; it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but a work around is to bind to `keydown` to capture which key has been pressed, and `input` if you want to obtain the value, including the key typed:

```
(function () {
    var keyCode;

    $('#txtInput')
        .on('keydown', function (e) {
            // value not updated yet
            keyCode = e.keyCode;

            // Enter key does not trigger 'input' events; manually trigger it
            if (e.keyCode === 13) $(this).trigger('input');
        })
        .on('input', function (e) {
            console.log(keyCode, this.value);
        });
}());
```

If you type 'a' the following occurs:

1. `keydown` fires.
2. `e.keyCode` is set to the ASCII value of the key pressed.
3. `this.value` is `''` (i.e. the same before 'a' has been typed).
4. `input` fires.
5. `e.keyCode` is `undefined`.
6. `this.value` is `'a'`.

You can also manually trigger an `input` event if the enter (13) key is pressed; `input` isn't fired by this key by default.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the `keypress` event on browsers with touch screens. I know that [you can't really detect touch screen screens](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/), though, so it leaves you with a few options that your situation will likely dictate.

1. Attach both events `keyup` and `keypress`. This would likely be dependent on how much processing is going on and if you are getting double-fires in some browsers.
2. Attempt to determine whether the browser is a touch screen (like using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)), and then attach a fallback handler like `change`.

Either way, you end up with two event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourid').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    // This will work
});
```