# DOM manipulation when typing not working on iPad but is working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, dom

There's been several questions asked on this topic but none have answered this question.

Basically, for this application I'm working on. When a user signs up, the user must enter a password in one `<input>` field and re-type it in another input field.

I'm using JavaScript DOM manipulation to do two things:

1. Alert the user if the confirmed password is dissimilar to the initial password.
2. Change the disabled attribute of the button from `false` to `true` when the passwords are the same.

To do this, I am adding an event listener to the input field where the user confirms the password. In this event listener, there's a conditional statement which assesses if the two password fields are the same. This event listener works with `oninput` and `onkeyup` on my Chrome browser and my iPhone 6 Safari browser. It does not work on my iPad Safari browser (which I assume is an older version).

```
const password2 = document.getElementById("password2");
    const password = document.getElementById("password");
    password2.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
        if (password2.value === password.value) {
            document.getElementById("registerButton").className = "btn btn-success w-100 submit-button"
            document.getElementById("registerButton").disabled = false;
            document.getElementsByClassName("showAlert")[0].setAttribute("class", "hideAlert");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("registerButton").className = "btn btn-secondary w-100 submit-button disabled"
            document.getElementById("registerButton").disabled = true;
            document.getElementsByClassName("hideAlert")[0].setAttribute("class", "showAlert");
        }
    });
```

Firstly, what event listeners should I use for this problem (if there are any)? If there aren't any, what other avenues should I look into?

Lastly, is there a better way to write this? Looks kind of clunky and not amateurish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [iOS 9 - keyup event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152960/ios-9-keyup-event-not-firing)

for touch screen devices, usually `keypress` works more often, but there was a suggestion to add the same function to both `keyup` and `keypress`, but if it works for you, `keydown` should be fine, so

```
const password2 = document.getElementById("password2");
const password = document.getElementById("password");
password2.addEventListener("keyup", eventify);

password2.addEventListener("keypress", eventify);

//OR simply

password2.addEventListener("keydown", eventify);
```

function eventify() {
if (password2.value === password.value) {
document.getElementById("registerButton").className = "btn btn-success w-100 submit-button"
document.getElementById("registerButton").disabled = false;
document.getElementsByClassName("showAlert")[0].setAttribute("class", "hideAlert");
} else {
document.getElementById("registerButton").className = "btn btn-secondary w-100 submit-button disabled"
document.getElementById("registerButton").disabled = true;
document.getElementsByClassName("hideAlert")[0].setAttribute("class", "showAlert");
}
}