# Javascript - keydown event not working in android

Tags: javascript, android

I created this script that will not let users to enter more than two decimal places in an input field.

```
  var limit = 2;
  jQuery("input.number").keydown(function(e) {
    if(!isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))){
      var inputVal = jQuery(this).val();
      if(inputVal.indexOf(".") > -1){
        var splitted = inputVal.split(".");
        var decimalCount =  splitted[1].length;
        if(decimalCount >= limit){
           e.preventDefault();
        }    
      }         
    }         

    });
```

The script works perfectly on desktop but when I test it in Chrome for Android, it doesn't seem to work. I tried changing the event to "on", "keypress(which is already deprecated)" but none of the options resolve the issue. Can someone please help me out?

**Update 1:**
I just noticed the script doesn't work for numpads only even in desktop. If I try to type from keyboard's right numpad, the script doesn't work. On the other hand, if I type the numbers from the top numbers right below the functional keys "f1-f12", the script works. That said, in mobile too, it opens numpad. Guess that's where the problem lies.

Comment: i think you should use keypress for touch events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940829/how-to-capture-the-onscreen-keyboard-keydown-and-keyup-events-for-touch-devi

Comment: *"The script works perfectly on desktop"* - Really? What if the user modifies the field value without using the keyboard?

Comment: @StephanHuewe, thank you for the link. I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: @nnnnnn, if you can please explain, I would surely update the script accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

### Include jQuery Mobile file

What you need to do is just include a jQuery file into your project. A file named jQuery.mobile.js or quite similar (ex. jQuery.ui.js) of any version can help you.

You can download it from : [Download | jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/download/)
I would like to suggest to use ResolveUrl while giving path for this file.