# How to store value of dynamically changing element as a static value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think this is a super basic question, but I'm a little confused.

If I want to take a snapshot of the text-value of a jQuery object that changes its values dynamically, how would I do this?

For example, `var text = $('#div').text()` will make text equal to whatever `div`'s text value is at the moment it is referenced, but I want it to always equal the `div`'s text value at the instant the expression was set.

Comment: look at event handlers like keyDown, keyPress in jQuery

Comment: I don't think this is a basic question. You could be explicit and do something like what Bucky24 or insertusernamehere propose below, but depending on how you plan to use the value you'll probably end up reimplementing something that looks like the dynamic bindings offered by frameworks like knockout.js or angularjs; check them out

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selector in a variable:

```
var container = $('#div');
```

Then you can access its text anytime you want. It will always be the most recent content:

```
if ('value' == container.text()) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using the `change` event.

IE:

```
var text = $("#div").text();
$("#div").on("change",function() {
    text = $("#div").text();
});
```

The `change` event will fire every time focus moves from the specified element, so it won't happen on every keystroke.

According to [How can I get jquery .val() AFTER keypress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063434/how-can-i-get-jquery-val-after-keypress-event), you can use the `keyup` event instead of change, to get the value immediately after it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could add them as a query string or keep them in a cookie.