# How can I get each character added in a form field using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an error message to a user, if he enters more characters in a text field than specified and this specification may change with the initial characters provided. Along with that, I need to process each character that user enters for some business purposes.
e.g.

Let's think of a credit card field.
[image]

Different credit card types have different Max Lengths. I would like to stop users from entering more characters in the field than their credit card type allows.

However, the credit card type can be detected only when the user provides few initial characters of the credit card.

My approach here is to try to detect credit card on every key press, and set the maxlength of the field according to credit card type detected. If not detected, keep the max length to 19 (which is maximum for all)

**What I have tried**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Event    | Problem                                              |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------|
|            |  Change will not be triggered until the user         |     
|  OnChange  | moves out of the field. Since I need this event      |
|            | on every char entered, this is not helpful           |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|            | It gives issues when a user presses the key for a    |
|  KeyDown   | longer duration. Characters are entered multiple     |
|            | times, but this event is triggered only once.        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------| 
|  KeyUP     | Same as above.                                       |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  KeyPress  | I am getting older value. The newly added character  |
|            | is not available. Hence incorrect calculation        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have an alternative of using time-out, but looking for better options.

My Question is different than [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063434/how-can-i-get-jquery-val-after-keypress-event) because of above mentioned reasons.

Please suggest a good solution for this.

Comment: Please show the related code.

Comment: use .change(function(){ ... }); instead of keypress();

Comment: @Ji_in_coding `change` only fires on `input` elements when they lose focus, which doesn't sound like the behaviour that the OP wants.

Comment: how about using the keydown.. and use "counter" variable?

Comment: @MohitKanwar you say you can't use `keyup`, but have you tried `keydown`?

Comment: *"I don't want to use "keyup" event, since if user triggers a keydown event but not keyup the value would be modified but my function won't be called."* Why is that a problem? The keyup event is triggered eventually, at which point you still have time to verify the length.

Comment: I have to trigger my event as soon as a character is entered in an input.
"keyup" event won't be triggered if a user presses a key for longer duration. Effect would be: multiple values entered but event triggered only once when "keyup" happens.

For the same reason, "keypress" and "keydown" are not suitable. If a key is pressed for longer duration, event is triggered only once.

Comment: Again, why is this an issue? You claim that is is an issue, but you don't explain why.

Comment: ahh.. the issue here is, I want to trigger my function as soon as a new character is entered in the input.
that means, the function must be triggered as soon as a new character is entered.

Comment: Try typing following in an input "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" without doing a keyup with r key.
events "keyup" and "keypress" would be triggered once, and "keyup" would be triggered once at end.
but I want to trigger my function each time "" changes to "r", "r" changes to "rr" and so on..

Comment: $(someTextInputField).attr('maxlength',validLength); try this

Comment: @Kishan I did that myself initially but this would stop insertion of the characters, this is not expected as per business requirements.  :(

Comment: @Kishan agree, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this serves most of the cases you need.

> This will work for every time the input is changed. And reset value if we enter more than allowed length.

```js
var limit = 10; //your input limit
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    var oldValue = $( "input[type='text']" ).val();
    $( "input[type='text']" ).on('keydown',function(e) {
        oldValue = $( this ).val();
    })
    $( "input[type='text']" ).on('input propertychange',function(e) {
        newValue = $(this).val();
        if(newValue.length > limit){
            $(this).val(oldValue);
            alert('String too long.');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/scds974a/4/).

Comment: using a combination of "input propertychange' and picking up value from "this" instead of jQuery selector worked for me.
However, I still don't understand why.
Can you explain your code?

Comment: @MohitKanwar `$(this)` means that we are getting the element which we have the binding on, I used it for exclusivity. `$( "input[type='text']" )` will work properly only if there is only one `input[type='text']` in the whole DOM.

Comment: yes, but somehow selecting field from jQuery returned older value and "this" returned newer value.

and what does .on('input propertychange') means?
Is it a different event? or when both input & propertychange are triggered ?

Comment: `input` is an html 5 event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input But there is issues in IE9 and lower versions. So for that we use `propertychange` event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx for better browser compatability.

Comment: Input acts on most of the cases where we copy and paste, text drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

try this

This will work when you change input

```js
$(someTextInputField).on('input',function(e){
  var txtLength =this.value.length;
  var validLength=4;
  if(txtLength > validLength){ 
      this.value=this.value.substr(0, validLength);
      alert("please enter only 4 character");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="someTextInputField" type="text">
```

Comment: "keyup" doesn't help if keypress event occurs but keyup doesn't. e.g. a long keypress event.

Comment: as stated by @Rejith R Krishnan 
input is an html 5 event. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input But there is issues in IE9 and lower versions. So for that we use propertychange event msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx for better browser compatability. –  Rejith R Krishnan

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var max_lenght = 5;
  
  $("#myTextInput").keypress(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > max_lenght - 1 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("max_length reached");  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myTextInput" placeholder="type here..." />
```

Try this code, which check on [keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) if `max_lenght` variable (which is 5 in this case) is reached (I added `-1` to the condition).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a 50ms delay to the keypress event. 
As follows.

```
$('#test').keypress(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#debug').append('<br>' + $('#test').val());
  }, 50);


});
```

see [example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwVRMR)

Answer (score 0):

here is a more simple (I believe) solution, as far as I understand the problem:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
var maxLength = 10;

$('#test').keypress(function(e){
  if($(this).val().length + 1 > maxLength){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    $('#result').html($(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(event.which));
  }
});
```

play with it here in Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGWQvG

Comment: this is called only once, in case of long keypress. which effects multiple characters to be entered