# onKeyPress Function Not Being Called Immediately

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    document.getElementById('my').onkeypress = function(event) {
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
    }
```

```html
    <input id='my' type="text">
```

Can someone explain to me what the `this` variable points to in the code above? Does it point to the input html element I grabbed from the `document.getElementById('my)`? Or does it point to the window object in the browser? Also what is the `event` parameter passed into the anonymous function?

For some reason when I run this code the value of each character is uppercased except the last char. So for example when I enter: a. The character a is not uppercased immediately it is only uppercased when I enter another letter. For example: Ab. Now b is not uppercased until I enter another letter after b: ABc. And this continues on. Can someone please explain why this happen?

Comment: Try using `onkeydown`?

Comment: `this` refers to the #my element.

Comment: If possible, could you recreate the problem in a code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: `onkeypress` fires before typed character is "submitted" to element value.

Comment: Listen to `keyup` event.

Comment: [onKeyPress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me what the this variable points to in the code above? Does it point to the input html element I grabbed from the document.getElementById('my)? Or does it point to the window object in the browser? Also what is the 'event' parameter passed into the anonymous function?

- `this` refers to the input element
- it's not an anonymous function, it's the declaration of the `onkeypress` function
- `event` is a parameter of the above function [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

The unexpected(?) behaviour is because the code is executed before the input field is updated, so only the previous value gets uppercased. To avoid it, you can use `onkeyup` event which fires after you release a key.

See it here:

```js
document.getElementById('my').onkeypress = function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
}

document.getElementById('my2').onkeyup = function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
}

document.getElementById('my3').oninput = function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
}
```

```html
<input id='my' type="text" placeholder="onkeypress">
<input id='my2' type="text" placeholder="onkeyup">
<input id='my3' type="text" placeholder="oninput">
```

*Thanks to @www139 for bringing up `oninput` in the comments as it is indeed the best solution for modern browsers* Please note it's HTML5-only and you can't get info like the key code, identifier, etc...

Comment: Yep, on key up seems like the answer :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063434/how-can-i-get-jquery-val-after-keypress-event

Comment: @DougieHauser, what about that, a duplicate? OP asked for explanation, not a jQuery solution.

Comment: Hi, it knows which key is pressed since the onKeyDown event, that's not the thing. The thing is that it gives you an opportunity to do something **before** the input happens, **on purpose**. Sometimes you want something else in the field to show up, sometimes you don't want anything or only a specific keys to respond, etc.

Comment: @Shomz, I discovered that if you use `window.setTimeout` with the function connected to onkeypress, it will behave just like the oninput solution!

Comment: Yes, that will launch an async event and put it in a queue, but is considered a hack and generally should be avoided (see this: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). The purest way to get everything working perfecly, even on the older browsers, is to combine onkeydown and onkeyup  (one for modifying the text while being pressed, and the other after being released) by assigning them the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple definition of the key events references from w3c.

> Tip: The order of events related to the onkeypress event:
>
> onkeydown onkeypress onkeyup Note: The onkeypress event is not fired
>   for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect
>   only whether the user has pressed a key, use onkeydown instead,
>   because it works for all keys.

This explains the oninput event; http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php

The oninput event has support of all the major browsers including IE 9 and later.

oninput better suits your needs than the "second-best" onkeyup because onkeyup only fires when the key is released. When you type, the new value is entered as soon as it is pressed, however it seems to add the new value to the box after the function fires. I will continue to experiment because I have another idea of how to do this but oninput seems like the best key event for this at the moment.

```js
document.getElementById('my').oninput = function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
}
```

```html
<input id='my' type="text">
```

**UPDATE**

You can still actually use the onkeypress event but you need to use a timeout to wait for the new value to be inserted into the text box before executing the function.

Here is another code snippet....

```js
document.getElementById('my').onkeypress = function(event) {
  var elem = this;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    elem.value = elem.value.toUpperCase()
  }, 0);
}
```

```html
<input id='my' type="text">
```

Comment: Was just about to give you credit for `oninput` but you wrote your own answer, so I can upvote it.

Comment: @Shomz stackoverflow needs more people like you :)

Comment: Haha, thank you, sir! There are many great people here on SO, and surely enough you are one of them.