# validate two input field using onkeypress event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate two input field on onkeypress event but when i am entering same value in both the field i am getting wrong message.
i tried to run the same code using onclick event and it was successful.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("txt1");
var b = document.getElementById("txt2");

function myFun() {
  if (a.value != b.value) {
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Did not match please recheck it</span>";

  } else if (a.value == b.value) {
    alert(a.value);
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:green'>match please recheck it</span>";

  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<p id="msg1"></p>
<input type="text" id="txt2" onkeypress="myFun()">
<p id="msg2"></p>
<input type="button" value="click">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Please help me solve this.
[its showing me wrong message even though value of both the filed is same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SV6C.png)

Comment: if you switch to using onkeyrelease, I think it should work for you

Comment: @ControlAltDel `onkeyrelease` is not a valid event in the DOM API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is not the correct event to use here because it fires as you are pressing a key (but before the character has been placed into the element) and it has been deprecated. Use [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event), which fires after the character has been placed into the field, instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
    
    <input type="text" id="txt1" >
    <p id="msg1"></p>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="myFun()">
    <p id="msg2"></p>
    <input type="button" value="click" >
    <script>
      var a = document.getElementById("txt1");
      var b = document.getElementById("txt2");
       
        function myFun() {
         if(a.value != b.value) {
            document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Did not match please recheck it</span>";
          } else if(a.value == b.value) {
            alert(a.value);
            document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:green'>match please recheck it</span>"; 
          }
       }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Additionally, you don't need `else if` here and can just use `else` because if the first test fails, then the two values must be equal.

Also, don't use `.innerHTML` if you can avoid it as there are performance and security issues to be concerned with. Instead, just set the text of a pre-existing HTML element with [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Lastly, instead of using inline event handlers and inline styles, separate your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Here's how that would look:

```css
.valid { color:green; }
.invalid { color:red; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
    
    <input type="text" id="txt1"><br>
    <input type="text" id="txt2">
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <input type="button" value="click" >
    <script>
      // Get your DOM references just once:
      var a = document.getElementById("txt1");
      var b = document.getElementById("txt2");
      var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
      
      // Set up your event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML
      b.addEventListener("keyup", myFun);
       
        function myFun() {
        if(a.value != b.value) {
            msg.textContent = "Did not match please recheck it";
            msg.classList.add("invalid");  // Apply pre-existing CSS class
            msg.classList.remove("valid"); // Remove pre-existing CSS class
          } else {
            msg.textContent = "match!"; 
            msg.classList.add("valid");    // Apply pre-existing CSS class  
            msg.classList.remove("invalid"); // Remove pre-existing CSS class            
          }
       }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks it helped.
But i saw a form where onkeypress event was used and it was working whenever user press the key.

Comment: @ManishPandey As I mentioned `keypress` is deprecated and, while it *can* still work in some use cases, it should not be used for the reason I stated. The `input` event is actually the best choice for running something after *any* change because mobile devices won't trigger any of the `key` events.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress` to capture the latest value in field.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063434/how-can-i-get-jquery-val-after-keypress-event)

```js
var a = document.getElementById("txt1");
var b = document.getElementById("txt2");

function myFun() {
  if (a.value != b.value) {
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Did not match please recheck it</span>";

  } else if (a.value == b.value) {
    alert(a.value);
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:green'>match please recheck it</span>";

  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<p id="msg1"></p>
<input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="myFun()">
<p id="msg2"></p>
<input type="button" value="click">
<p id="demo"></p>
```